# extract a specific value from a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, series

i got this code:

```
 df=df\
    .assign(SUM_pre = lambda x: x['value1'].rolling(???).sum())
```

where i'm tring to sum the values of the column value1 on a specific rolling. the fact is that the rolling changes throught time and the value of rolling is saved in another column, like the following:

```
       ID   span_pre   value1  value2
0      A       0        0.1       0
1      A       1        0.0       0
2      A       2        0.1       0
3      A       3        0.1       0
4      A       3        0.1       0
5      A       3        0.1       0
6      S       0        0.2       0
7      S       1        0.2       0
8      S       2        0.2       0
9      S       3       None       1
10     S       3       None       1
11     S       3       None       1
```

i've tried:

```
 df=df\
    .assign(SUM_pre = lambda x: x['value1'].rolling(x.span_pre).sum())
```

but the output is:
**ValueError: window must be an integer**
that is coherent: x.span_pre is a serie.
can you help me to understand how to extract each time the value in the column span_pre without doing to much cycles?
so my final output should be:

```
       ID   span_pre   value1  value2  SUM_pre
0      A       0        0.1       0      0.1
1      A       1        0.0       0      0.1
2      A       2        0.1       0      0.2
3      A       3        0.1       0      0.2
4      A       3        0.1       0      0.3
5      A       3        0.1       0      0.3
6      S       0        0.2       0      0.2
7      S       1        0.2       0      0.4
8      S       2        0.2       0      0.6
9      S       3       None       1      0.4
10     S       3       None       1      0.2
11     S       3       None       1     None
```

Answer (score 1):

*(please check your output before)*

I slightly modified your dataframe to avoid error and confusing:

```
df['value1'] = df['value1'].replace({'None': np.NaN}).astype(float)
df.index += 100
```

```
>>> df
    ID  span_pre  value1  value2
100  A         0     0.1       0  # [0:1]  -> 0.0
101  A         1     0.0       0  # [0:2]  -> 0.1 + 0.0
102  A         2     0.1       0  # [0:3]  -> 0.1 + 0.0 + 0.1
103  A         3     0.1       0  # [0:4]  -> 0.1 + 0.0 + 0.1 + 0.1
104  A         3     0.1       0  # [1:5]  -> 0.0 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
105  A         3     0.1       0  # [2:6]  -> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
106  S         0     0.2       0  # [6:7]  -> 0.2
107  S         1     0.2       0  # [6:8]  -> 0.2 + 0.2
108  S         2     0.2       0  # [6:9]  -> 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2
109  S         3     NaN       1  # [6:10] -> 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + NaN
110  S         3     NaN       1  # [7:11] -> 0.2 + 0.2 + NaN + NaN
111  S         3     NaN       1  # [8:12] -> 0.2 + NaN + NaN + NaN
```

You can iterate over each row and slice the dataframe `[curr_idx-span_pre:curr_idx+1]`:

```
df['SUM_pre'] = [df['value1'].iloc[i-w:i+1].sum()
                     for i, w in enumerate(df['span_pre'])]
```

```
>>> df
    ID  span_pre  value1  value2  SUM_pre
100  A         0     0.1       0      0.1
101  A         1     0.0       0      0.1
102  A         2     0.1       0      0.2
103  A         3     0.1       0      0.3
104  A         3     0.1       0      0.3
105  A         3     0.1       0      0.4
106  S         0     0.2       0      0.2
107  S         1     0.2       0      0.4
108  S         2     0.2       0      0.6
109  S         3     NaN       1      0.6
110  S         3     NaN       1      0.4
111  S         3     NaN       1      0.2
```

Or use a [custom window rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html#custom-window-rolling) by subclassing `BaseIndexer`:

```
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer

class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):
    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed):
        right = 1 + np.arange(num_values, dtype='int64')
        left = right - self.index_array.values - 1
        return left, right

indexer = CustomIndexer(df['span_pre'])
df['SUM_pre'] = df['value1'].rolling(indexer).sum()
```

Comment: thank you very much, is not so different on what i did right now but your list comprehension is so much smarter and clearer than mine. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to read that. Don't forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem.